# INSERT failing on Form Submission from Page

Tags: c#, forms, file-upload, submit

I have prepared this Form to upload a book to the server side db with its image.

I have to read and retrieve the book on another page thus saving image path in database and also saving image in a folder "upload" ..

I tried debugging the code, problem is that the debug arrow does not even enters the button click event.

On designing section, there's just a simple form comprising of textboxes retrieving client's information on book and also a file upload controller, within same button click event.

```
public partial class UploadBooks : System.Web.UI.Page
{

string strcon = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StudentConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // add session name
    //Label3.Text = Session["StudFirstName"].ToString();
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // image uploading
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/jpeg")
            {
                if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength < 102400)
                {
                    string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
                    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads") + filename);
                    Label2.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
                }
                else
                    Label2.Text = "Upload status: The file has to be less than 100 kb!";
            }
            else
                Label2.Text = "Upload status: Only JPEG files are accepted!";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label2.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
        }
    }
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Books (StudId,BookId,Title,Author,Description,Price,Owner,Phone_no,ImagePath) values (@sid,@bid,@t,@a,@d,@p,@o,@n,@i)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sid", Label4.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bid", Label1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@t", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", TextBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", TextBox3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", TextBox6.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@o", TextBox4.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", TextBox5.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i", FileUpload1.FileName);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        Response.Write("1 Book Added");
    }


}
}
```

Comment: Have you subscribed the button to this event?  `Button1.Click += Button1_Click;`

Comment: ERROR : Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Books' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your clarification in the comment it is clear that you are trying to INSERT a value into the table's `IDENTITY` column.

Most likely it is the `StudId` or the `BookID` column.

Remove the identity column from your `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue()` statement and your INSERT string and you should be good.

SQL Automatically inserts this value and increments it based on the previous values.

If your IDENTITY column is `StudId` then your insert string should look like:

```
"Insert into Books (BookId,Title,Author,Description,Price,Owner,Phone_no,ImagePath) values (@bid,@t,@a,@d,@p,@o,@n,@i)"
```

If your IDENTITY column is `BookId` then it should look like:

```
"Insert into Books (StudId,Title,Author,Description,Price,Owner,Phone_no,ImagePath) values (@sid,@t,@a,@d,@p,@o,@n,@i)"
```

Then just delete the `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue()` line for the related parameter.

Comment: I'm inserting the values into books having bookid...i have had it removed before i read this but the error still comes up as "Error converting data type nvarchar to float." .. i don't know which data type to change n now.. caz i have not set anything to nvarchar...but varchar(50) n all numerical values like id,phone_no and price to float.

Comment: Well you are trying to pass a string (or a null) into a numeric field... that's a whole other issue man.  Check the values in your text boxes before submitting and make sure the values match the types in your database.

Comment: sorry dude...that was becaz i misplaced textboxes values...but now i think another error popped up regarding foreign key for studid...should i remove it from cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue() ?? thou i want it to insert the studid value to my db corresponding to the books they upload..:(

Comment: ERROR : The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Books_ToTable". The conflict occurred in database "C:\USERS\PUJAN MSP\DOCUMENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2012\WEBSITES\MYCOLLEGERP\APP_DATA\STUDENT.MDF", table "dbo.Student", column 'StudId'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: I think i got it...just one more favor... can u answer or suggest any links to help me on topic of connecting more than 1 mmasterpages ??